# Rails and ActiveRecord - Finding Rows by IP returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model in Rails called `Statistics` and every time someone visits my page, I log their IP in the model and save. This is how my model currently looks:

```
Statistics(id: integer, ip: string, ...);
```

An example record return would be:

```
#<Statistics id: 700, ip: "10.0.2.2", ...>
```

But when I enter the Rails Console, and try to locate the record:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :175 > Statistics.find_all_by_ip("10.0.2.2")
Statistics Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "statistics".* FROM "statistics" WHERE "statistics"."ip" = '10.0.2.2'
=> []
```

I always get an empty return..

Are they any quirks to Rails for IP addresses that I don't know of? I just can't seem to figure out why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Any reason you're calling `find_all_by_ip` instead of just `find_by_ip`?

Comment: Oh sorry, it was just some remnants of my code, but either way, `find_by_ip` and `find_all_by_ip` both return nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first assumption is that the IP address was stored using the value from an `Addrinfo`, whereas SQLite uses UTF. This assumes you're using SQLite, which you don't mention.

[See my previous answer I gave covering this in some detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7919774/438992)

Comment: That did it! I was using `request.ip` and storing that directly into the database. And you are correct, I was using SQLite. Thanks so much!